# Calculating days a case is active between two dates

Tags: powerbi

I need help solving a problem. I am trying to calculate active days a case was open between two dates in PowerBi. Sample table would be something like this

[image]

We would like to be able to visualize how many cases were active in certain month and compare it to the previous years. I have tried many ways to complete this and failed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide your output in a tabular form? In your example `Case Number` 124 is active?

Comment: If it opened one day at 23:59 and closed the next day at 00:01, would that be 0 days, 1 days, or 2 days?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Date Dimension that does not have an active relationship to your Case data.
[image: Date Dimension]

Create a slicer on that date dimension
[image: Date Slicer]

Create a measure called Active to filter your case data

```
Active = 
    VAR IsActive = 
        IF (
            SELECTEDVALUE('Case'[Open Date])<=MAX('Date'[Date]) &&
            (SELECTEDVALUE('Case'[Close Date])>=Min('Date'[Date]) || ISBLANK(SELECTEDVALUE('Case'[Close Date]))),
            1,
            0
        )
    RETURN
        IsActive
```

[image: Active measure]

Add the Active measure to the filters on your visual that you want to show active dates for and set Active is 1

[image: Filter on Active]

Now if a case date falls inside the selected date range, you will see the case results

Example1 - Full date range coverage
[image: Full date range coverage]
Example2 - Partial date range coverage
[image: Partial date range coverage]

Note that a blank end date is assumed to be active providing the open date is before the slicers closed date